# Killing Java Process from C# Console App

Tags: c#, java, .net

I posted about this a little while ago, but I resolved the other issue and ran into one more. I am about to deploy this program to 28 hosting machines so I want to make sure this is working before I do so.

I wrote a little c# NET application that is basically a wrapper for a Java application, when my app starts, the Java app starts, when my app closes, it closes, and so on.

Everything works properly except that when I close my application, the Java application continues to run. When I create the process, I store the Process var in a variable outside of the methods, and then use that when my application goes to shutdown. For whatever reason though it is not terminating the Java application.

```
class Program
{
    private static Process minecraftProcess;

    public static void LaunchMinecraft(String file, String memoryValue)
    {
        String memParams = "-Xmx" + memoryValue + "M" + " -Xms" + memoryValue + "M ";
        String args = memParams + "-jar " + file + " nogui";
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", args);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        try
        {
            //using (Process minecraftProcess = Process.Start(processInfo))
            using (minecraftProcess = Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                minecraftProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Log Error
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Arguments CommandLine = new Arguments(args);

        // Hook ProcessExit Event
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(Current_ProcessExit);

        if (CommandLine["file"] != null && CommandLine["memory"] != null)
        {
            // Launch the Application (Command Line Parameters)
            LaunchMinecraft(CommandLine["file"], CommandLine["memory"]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Launch the Application (Default Parameters)
            LaunchMinecraft("minecraft_server.jar", "1024");
        }
    }

    static void Current_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // If we have an active Minecraft Service, Shut it down
        if (minecraftProcess != null)
        {
            minecraftProcess.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint onto the minecraftProcess.Kill() line does it break there?  If it does execute does it execute cleanly i.e. with no exceptions

Comment: It looks like the Process "minecraftProcess" is null. Is there a better way I can keep that around to use?

Comment: Actually it looks like the return value of Process.Start() is a boolean, not the actual process itself so that makes sense now. Do you know how I can get the ID of the one I created though since I will have more than one running?

Comment: Have you consider running the JVM in the same process?  Either using JNI or IKVM works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `Sleep` in a `ProcessExit` handler.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) states:

> The total execution time of all
>   ProcessExit event handlers is limited,
>   just as the total execution time of
>   all finalizers is limited at process
>   shutdown. The default is two seconds.
>   An unmanaged host can change this
>   execution time by calling the
>   ICLRPolicyManager::SetTimeout method
>   with the OPR_ProcessExit enumeration
>   value.

Comment: Yeah, I just added that in there to see if I could prolong it and print out some values. The issue I mentioned originally is still there regardless of wether I Sleep or not.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just realized the minecraftProcess variable is static.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you did not solve this issue by yourself but:

- You should be aware that there are **Start** methods for instances (returning bool) and static (returning a object).
- You should not use **using** with something other than using-local variables!

Just this should work fine:

```
minecraftProcess = Process.Start(processInfo)
minecraftProcess.WaitForExit();
```